# How to put values in a column into new columns in one row based on values in one another column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
V1   V2
a    2
a    3
a    4
b    3
b    7
```

I want to convert it into

```
V1 V2 V3 V4
a  2  3  4
b  3  7
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


valus=np.rot90(np.array([["b","b","a","a","a"],[7,3,4,3,2]]))
col=['v1','v2']


data=pd.DataFrame(valus,columns=col)

newcol=['v2', 'V3' ,'V4']


aa=data.query('v1 =="a"')
aa2=data.query('v1 =="b"')
aaa=list(aa["v2"])
bbb=list(aa2["v2"])


list=[aaa,bbb]

v1=['a','b']

newdata=pd.DataFrame(list,columns=newcol,index=v1)
newdata.index.names = ['v1']

print (newdata)
```

out:

v1---v2---v3---v4

a-----2-----3------4

b-----3-----7-----None

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` on `V1` and use `cumcount` to create a new column `V`, then use `pivot` with index as `V1` and columns as `V` to reshape the dataframe, finally use `drop_level` + `rename_axis`:

```
df['V'] = 'V' + df.groupby('V1').cumcount().add(2).astype(str)
df1 = df.pivot('V1', 'V').droplevel(0, 1).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
print(df1)
  V1   V2   V3   V4
0  a  2.0  3.0  4.0
1  b  3.0  7.0  NaN
```

Comment: @AnandSrivastava Does this answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

Groupby `V1`. Pass `v2` to a list create a new df and Transpose. Reset index and rename the columns of resultant frame.

```
 df2=df.groupby('V1')['V2'].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.tolist()).T)\
.reset_index().drop(columns=['level_1'])
df2.columns=['v1','v2','v3','v4']


v1  v2  v3   v4
0  a   2   3  4.0
1  b   3   7  NaN
```